# PBKDF2 in Android differ from Ios and node.js output

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, password-encryption, pbkdf2

I have implemented PBKDF2 with Hmac-SHA1 in Android with following code.

```
 private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000;
        private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256; // bits

        public static String hashPassword(String password, String salt)
                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
            char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
            byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes();

            PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, saltBytes, ITERATIONS,
                    KEY_LENGTH);
            SecretKeyFactory key = SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            byte[] hashedPassword = key.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
            return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(hashedPassword));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(hashPassword("abcd1234",
                    "6c646576656c6f7065726c3139383540676d61696c2e636f6d"));
    }
```

it gives me following key as output

**138e52b955673f2b580b6a02283e3f5c52dce03e2dcdb140e4ad24e4347c2568**

and node.js output is

**8462884f256a94cce232b9227bc73072763be8824af94807101ff0a322e20388**

the node.js output is what I want in android which I successfully got in ios.

this is my test website for getting node.js output

https://jswebcrypto.azurewebsites.net/demo.html#/pbkdf2

Key Size: 256

Iterations: 10000

Passphrase: abcd1234

salt : 6c646576656c6f7065726c3139383540676d61696c2e636f6d

I have no idea what is happening in android. Any help would be appriciated.